# Getting single line from CMD response c# and put it into textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, adb, redirectstandardoutput

So I want to get the response of `adb devices` put through a cmd window and then to show up in a text box. 
At this moment in time I have this code:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "";
process = Process.Start(startInfo);
**process.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb devices"); 
connected_devices.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

At this moment in time I am getting the following results:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Rather than **just**:

```
list of attached devices
xxxxxxxx       device
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: everyone keeps reinventing their own wheel. just use https://madb.codeplex.com

Comment: I dont need it. I would rather code it myself and then make it open source...

Comment: if you ever decide to make a living by doing software development - get rid of your NIH syndrome. also if you have not noticed - `madb` is open source

Comment: I know it is but I'm a hobby coder. I do it to help others and why use madb when you can just include the adb.exe and fastboot.exe along with the required .dll's as it would make the program lighter (considering the toolbox contains stock images that won't be included in the open source release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().

Comment: But I specifically want `list of attached devices
xxxxxxxx       device` rather than the whole speal that comes with that.

Comment: Try to directly start adb instead of through cmd.exe. Then maybe ReadLine does what you want.

Comment: Thanks. The original worked. Just had to modify the arguments and directly start adb. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the above post this is my solution

```
startInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "devices";
process = Process.Start(startInfo);
connected_devices.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

and it printed out:

`List of devices attached 
xxxxxxx device`

which is what I wanted